# Inconsistent behaviour with pages created with onenote-api - fixed with OneNote update

Tags: android, ios, onenote, onenote-api

Looking for some help please from the onenote team!
 I have a page generated by the onenote api that could be opened by the previous version of onenote for mac, ios and android but now fails (most other pages generated by the onenote-api work fine). It still opens fine in the online version of onenote. If I copy the page to the same section online then both pages can be opened on the tablet devices.
It would be great to work out if this is a problem in the onenote-api or the recent onenote update.
I'm happy to send a copy of the affected onenote section or link to a dummy notebook.
The current work around is to roll all the android tablets at work back to the previous working version, but this is not so easy with ios devices.
**FURTHER FURTHER UPDATE**
Thanks Vishaal. The latest ios + android updates fix the issue.
Cheers Steve

Comment: Hi codeye, I'm a dev on the OneNote team. Thanks for the update. Could you share a link to the section and/or notebook?

Also, what version of the SDKs are you using and what versions are the devices? If I understand correctly the newer versions of the devices have trouble opening a specific page that you generated with the API, so the bug could be with either the API or the client code, so we can narrow it down.

I've created an issue to track this internally and will be digging into it.

Comment: Thanks Vishaal. I've edited the question to include a sample notebooks. Cheers Steve